# Rails 4 + Google: Display Reviews on webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-api, google-authentication

I have been reading through the various authentication methods for Google but they seem to require signing into my admin google account, when all I want to do is display reviews on my webpage.

Is there a non-authenicated way of achieving this since it is public data?

Answer (score 0):

Per the Google documentation you can make a `GET` request to the reviews API. https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/review-data#list_all_reviews

Looks like you need to hit `https://mybusiness.googleapis.com/v3/accounts/<your_account_name>/locations/<your_location_name>/reviews`

Comment: I wish it were that easy.  When you make the request it let's you know its unauthenticated.  It requires a token in the header of the request and that token is only valid temporarily.